# Creating an insert/update/delete trigger for Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a question that I've yet to find an answer to after some research.  Is there a way in Code First for Entity to create an Insert/Update/Delete Trigger?  Currently I cannot find anything and the only thing eluding to it was suggestions of using code to do whatever work (insert/update/delete) after a method fires.

Comment: You can probably do this in a customer database initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework currently does not support creating triggers on the database itself, nor does there appear to be any in the near future (see what's being implemented for EF 6 [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap)).

The only solution that you have is to do whatever it is you wanted to do after the Insert/Update/Delete finishes, preferably in your business logic (or, even better, in your repositories if you want to set it up like in [this blog post](http://sitecore.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/the-repo-man)).

Comment: That's what I feared.  Seems like something they would want to invest in.  I have a way around it though since I have a start up script when my project is first deployed.  I could add the trigger then.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 on the answer, "preferably in your business logic" is the right way of doing things.